# "Consume" notification in NiFi wait/notification pattern

Tags: apache-nifi, notify

I got a source process that emits 20 FlowFiles triggered on file basis (20 files come into a subdirectory of a monitored directory).

As soon as the first of the 20 Files enters the System I want to trigger a waiting process. This waiting process is dependent on all other 20 files being converted already.

After the conversion is done I trigger a "Notify" process. Where the `Release Signal Identifier` is configured as the path. As soon as the count hits 20 I want to release the other process chain. But after this chain is tiggered I want to reset the count to 0.

How do I configure that the counter is set to 0 again? I looked into my MapCache file and I see an entry for EVERY file that went through the chain where each count 1,2,3...20 is there.

Comment: Could you please add a diagram?